# How to return a local PDF document in a View in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, pdf, rendering

I am trying to show a locally stored PDF document on my MVC Web application.
What I have tried so far is not quite useful. I tried with the **object** tag in html but it just says : `Access denied`.

```
<object type="application/pdf" data="LocalPathToMyFile" width="958" height="726" id="fbContainer" style="visibility: visible;"> 
        <param name="wmode" value="transparent">
        <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="always">
        <param name="bgcolor" value="#ffffff">
    </object>
```

Answer (score 0):

We put them in an iframe like this.

```
   <iframe id="external" src"yourSource" width="100%"  style="background:#FFF; height:100%;  margin:0; padding:0; overflow:scroll"></iframe>
```

if that gives you a similar error probably permisions.

Comment: It works on IE but I don't know why it doesn't open it in the Chrome and Mozilla.

Comment: @mathinvalidnik what error does it give you in the chrome console?

Comment: Not allowed to load local resource: file:///C:/Users/.../MyPdf.pdf

Comment: Oh its a local path I thought it was directly in the project. Chrome and mozilla both have more strict security and will not allow this. We had the same problem till we switched it to our server. If there is only a couple though you can add to your local project.